# Display mysql exception by hibernate javafx

Tags: mysql, hibernate, exception, javafx

I have this code:
Class comuni

```
package com.saverio.Anagrafica.Entita;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

@Entity
 @Table
public class Comuni {
private final SimpleIntegerProperty id;
private final SimpleStringProperty codice;
private final SimpleStringProperty comune;
private final SimpleStringProperty cap;
private final SimpleStringProperty regione;
private final SimpleStringProperty provincia;


public Comuni() {
    this(0, null, null, null, null, null);
}


public Comuni(int id,String codice, String comune, String cap, String regione, String provincia) {
    super();
    this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    this.codice = new SimpleStringProperty(codice);
    this.comune = new SimpleStringProperty(comune);
    this.cap = new SimpleStringProperty(cap);
    this.regione = new SimpleStringProperty(regione);;
    this.provincia = new SimpleStringProperty(provincia);
}

public void setId (int id){
    this.id.set(id);
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
public final int getId(){
    return id.get();
}

public void setCodice (String codice){
    this.codice.set(codice);
}   

@Column(name="codice", unique=true)
public final String getCodice(){
    return codice.get();
}


public void setComune (String comune){
    this.comune.set(comune);
}

@Column(name="comune")
public final String getComune(){
    return comune.get();
}



public void setCap (String cap){
    this.cap.set(cap);
}

@Column(name="cap")
public final String getCap(){
    return cap.get();
}


public void setRegione (String regione){
    this.regione.set(regione);
}

@Column(name="regione")
public final String getRegione(){
    return regione.get();
}



public void setProvincia (String provincia){
    this.provincia.set(provincia);
}

@Column(name="provincia")
public final String getProvincia(){
    return provincia.get();
}
```

}

Class Comuni.Dao

```
public static void insertDati(Comuni comune) throws HibernateException  {
    Configuration con = new Configuration();
    con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(comune);
    tr.commit();
    session.close();
    sf.close();
}
```

SchedaComuneController Class:

```
@FXML
void salvaComune(ActionEvent event) {
    Comuni comune = new Comuni();
    comune.setCodice(textCodice.getText());
    comune.setCap(textCap.getText());
    comune.setComune(textComune.getText());
    comune.setRegione(cmbRegioni.getValue());
    comune.setProvincia(cmbProvincia.getValue());
    try{
    ComuniDao.insertDati(comune);
    btnSalva.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }catch(HibernateException  ex){
        //if (ex.getErrorCode() == 1062){
            AlertDialog.datiBox("Attenzione, esiste gia' un comune con questo codice", "Errore!", null);
            System.out.println(ex);
        //}
    }
```

When run salvaComune method i have in eclipse console this exception: "org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
I know that error is Duplicate entry but I want to diplay the mysql exception by System.out.println. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to print the stacktrace of the exception to `System.out` rather than, say, `System.err`. The `java.lang.Throwable` class (which all exceptions/errors inherit from) has the following method: `printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream)`. Luckily the field `System.out` is a `java.io.PrintStream`.

For your use case: `ex.printStackTrace(System.out)`

---

**Update due to comment:**

You state in your question that the specific class of `HibernateException` is `ConstraintViolationException`. Looking at the documentation that class has a method `getConstraintName()` which might give you some of the information you want.

Also, `ConstraintViolationException` extends from `JDBCException` which itself wraps the checked "lower level" `java.sql.SQLException`. The class `JDBCException` provides methods for getting the SQL state and error code as well as direct access to the underlying `SQLException` which might be able to give you even more of the information you want. The message of the `SQLException` itself might carry the more specific reason as to why it was thrown.

However, if you want to present this information on the console you *might*, depending on how you want the error to look, have to manually create an error message and print it to `System.out`.

Comment: Thanks Slaw. i don't undertstand why HibernateException  display a generic exception "could not execute statement" and not really error, in this case Duplicate entry '12345' for key 'codice'. I want to diplay it.